# Возможно ли ограничение зоны поиска DOM?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли, например, для метода `getElementById`, сократить область поиска со всей страницы до какой-либо отдельной части HTML-документа? В примере

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="element">
    </div>
</div>
```

можно конечно, сначала найти `container`, а потом внутри него уже искать `element`, но container-то мы ищём опять же по всему документу, а это нерационально в больших документах. Можно ли как-то ограничить зону поиска?

Comment: Насколько я понял читая Кантора об внутреннем устройстве поисковых методов,id хранятся в виде хэш таблицы и элемент возвращается сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что при построении дерева все ссылки на элементы ID собираю в одном месте и потом используются для быстрого поиска по дереву. Поэтому то, что вы хотите оптимизировать и так уже оптимизировано. Но не буду этого утверждать.

В общем как один из вариантов, можно натыкать меток и ограничивать ими, если уж так хочется. По крайней мере они точно собраны в одном месте и до них легко добраться.

```js
console.log(
  document.anchors["part_2"].innerText
)
```

```html
<div>
  <a name="part_1">
    part 1
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a name="part_2">
    part 2
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a name="part_3">
    part 3
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Даже не могу сообразить для чего тебе это надо.  `id` - идентификатор уникальный и может быть только в единственном экземпляре на все странице. И даже  если данный экземпляр будет в начале страницы или где-то далеко и обернут в тысячу родительских блоков, это ни как не повлияет  на скорость его обнаружения.... Ну может на миллионную долю секунды....  Так что в этом нет ни какого смысла....

Comment: Air, благодарю Вас за ответ! Объясню, зачем это мне нужно, может что ещё порекомендуете. Я вот просто думаю: как можно выиграть в производительности при выполнении затратной операции поиска по DOM-древу? В движке React JS эту задачу решили хорошо, но что если не я хочу использовать React JS?

Comment: Производительность можно прекрасно поднять правильным грамотным кодом....  А не поиском элементов в `DOM`-дереве...

Comment: Я говорю не о производительности JS в целом, а об оптимизации операции выборки DOM-элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно.

Это имеет смысл для поиска например по имени тега, классу или более сложному селектору.

Но для поиска по `id` это смысла не имеет, так как все `id` хранятся в хэш таблице и поиск по ней происходит очень быстро (за константное время операций), и там уже нечего ускорять.

```js
var area = document.getElementById("searchArea");

var els = area.getElementsByTagName("p");

/* можно и по id поискать, но скорее всего это будет медленнее чем поиском через document.getElementById */
var el1 = area.querySelector("#id1");

console.log(Array.from(els));
console.log(el1);
```

```html
<p>
  some text
</p>

<div id="searchArea">

  <p id="id1">11</p>
  <p>22</p>

</div>

<p>
  some text
</p>
```

Comment: после `var area = document.getElementById("searchArea");`  узел уже найден...   К чему его искать повторно `var el1 = area.querySelector("#id1");`, что это дает? Сто пудов времени пойдет больше....

Comment: @Air на первом шаге ищется узел области поиска, на втором ищется то что внутри него. при большом количестве поиска внутри, это может дать реальное ускорение.

Comment: @Air Именно с поиском по id это может и не дать ускорения, но с поисками например по классу или имени тега, возможно ускорение, хотя гарантировать не могу, надо тестировать, но то что я написал это ответ на вопрос, можно ли искать и если можно то как, я написал. а ускорит или нет, это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Вот щас искал и не нашел статью, в которой говориться следующее, что   `document.getElementById()` чем `document.querySelector()`...    Обещаю найду статью пришлю

Comment: @Air дополнил ответ.

Comment: Дима, дорогой, слова в ответе совершенно правильные, но на мой взгляд, пример противоречит словам выше))))  Честно, со всем уважением))))

Comment: @Air да, я думал над этим... добавлю комментарий для пояснения

Comment: И еще. Когда парсер выстраивает `DOM`, он уже знает что где находится....  и когда `js` спрашивает его о каком-то узле, парсер ему указывает, ищи в этой куче или ищи в этой куче...  Но если он к нему обращается так `document.getElementById()`...  А если запрос методом `document.querySelector()`? то парсер говорит,  пройтись по всем кучам и найдешь...

Comment: @Air да, скорее всего так, хотя возможно что он как-то обрабатывает `#`, но скорее нет, чем да.

Comment: Поверь нет.....

Comment: @Air хорошо, исправляю

Comment: @Air _Поверь нет....._ - зачем верить? давай доказательства

Comment: @Grundy, ищу статью... не помню куда сохранил...))

Comment: @Air не совсем, но дополнительные действия при использовании querySelector все же происходят: http://ryanmorr.com/abstract-away-the-performance-faults-of-queryselectorall/ Правда статья от 2014, а за это время многое могло поменяться.